# Edit post bug - Something Bad Happened!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, asking-questions

Enter to this link and you'll get the following message: `Oops! Something Bad Happened!`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/submit

Basically, I got this message when I tried to post an question and encounter validation error (do to missing tag or something), so the page returned to me with this new url. after clicking on the new url in the address bar to refresh the page, I got this error page.

I just want to make a point, **why use a different url for the http post action?** using the same url, for both get and post, will reduce the confusing for the url changing in a validation failed situations.

Comment: I see your point, but it does something different for me. I get a captcha if I try to refresh the form when it contains validation errors (presumably because this behavior is interpreted as a bot). Then it tells me I have to resubmit the form information. If I resubmit, I get the above Url with a GUID attached to it. If I refresh again, I wind up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. So I never actually get the `Oops, something bad happened` unless I click on your actual link posted above, or type it directly into the address bar.

Comment: Right. I don't have time to reproduce this error now, but this changes of the captcha is new in the last month or so, so I can tell that this steps reproduce the error before that change. sorry to bring it up just now, but the point is still actual.

Comment: Please give me some rep, I want to post another 2 questions without waiting 20 minutes... :)

Comment: @Robert I updated a repro steps.

Comment: Do you perform QA testing for a living? :)

Comment: Right now yes. That's why I didn't post it months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Even more confusing is if you have a Captcha on validation failure then you get yet another address, except for this one works as expected. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/submit?s=6fe51e44-84a2-480a-8f66-95b2414bc250 and redirects to the /ask page.

Answer (score -2):

Basically you lack the GUID, so I now return a 404 rather than a 500 if that happens.

Comment: Look, the original idea behind this point, is to know why don't you use the same url for both get and post actions...

Comment: I tried to remove the `status-completed` tag, but I can't.

Comment: @stacker I suggest you retag the `[bug]` tag to either `[support]` or `[discussion]`, since the bug is fixed and what you really want now is  a `why does this work this way` answer.

Comment: @waiwai933 done.